# oop Class use in multiple subs with out creating new instance

Tags: vb.net, class, oop

struggling with using oop and passing data around. i want to use my customer class, containting certain data to be used in more than one class.

```
Public Class customer
   Inherits person

 End Class 



Public Class person
    Inherits RegexValidator

Private name As String
Private lastName As String
Private Email As String
Private Postcode As String
Private Number As String



Public Property Firstname As String
    Get
        Return name
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        name = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property LastN As String
    Get
        Return lastName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        lastName = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

Soo in Another form "Edit Customer" i populate the customer with data but now i want to use that same customer in my other form "Add appointment" i need something like this

Class AddAppointment

dim AppCustomer as customer 
Appcustomer = EditCustomer.Customer

or something along those lines or better would be just to get it strait from my customer Class

Appcustomer = customer

thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass the instance into the other form.  In your AddAppointmentForm, change the constructor (Sub New) to take an instance of your class and store it in a class variable:

```
Public Class AddAppointmentForm

    'Class level variable in AddAppointmentForm
    Private _customer As Customer

    'Constructor takes Customer object as a parameter
    Public Sub New(appCustomer As Customer)
        _customer = appCustomer
    End Sub

End Class
```

Then in the first form, you would create the instance and pass it to the AddAppointmentForm:

```
'In the main form create the customer
Dim appCustomer As New Customer

'When ready to show the AddAppointmentForm, pass the customer to it
Dim apptForm As New AddAppointmentForm(appCustomer)
```